# WordPress is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, http-error

I am creating a custom plugin that involves features to upload CSV and use the data in the sheet.

Here is the function that I used to upload csv file

```
<h1 align="center">Upload CSV</h1>
<!--    Upload CSV File-->
<form action="https://wordpress-317991-1667562.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/plugins/kdlcsv/file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Choose the File to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

And then in the `file-upload.php` file the following code.

```
//1.0 Load the Basic Files
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require( $parse_uri[0] . '/wp-load.php' );

//2.0 Setting the directory for uploading
$target_dir = "uploads/";

//3.0 Name of the file to upload
$target_file= $target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

//4.0 Variable to check if the upload is properly carried out
$uploadOk=1;

//5.0 Extracting the File Extension
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//6.0 To check if it is an actual file or fake
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check= filesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        echo "Actual File is uploaded";
        $uploadOk=1;
    } else {
        echo "File has an error";
        $uploadOk=0;
    }
}

//7.0 To check if the file already exists in the director
if(file_exists($target_file)){
    echo "Sorry, file already exists";
    $uploadOk=0;
}

//8.0 To Limit File Size
if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]>100000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your File size is too large";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

//9.0 To Limit File Type
if($imageFileType!="csv" && $imageFileType!="xlsx" && $imageFileType!="xls"){
    echo "Sorry only CSV, XLSX and XLS files are allowed to upload";
}

//10.0 complete the file upload
if($uploadOk==0){
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded";
}
else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)){
        echo "The file ".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])."has been uploaded";
        echo basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        return kdl_csv_to_data_array(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your File.";
    }
}

//11.0 Function to convert CSV file to Data
function kdl_csv_to_data_array($filename){
    
    //11.1 Test the file name received
    echo $filename;
    
    //11.2 The Nested array to hold all the arrays
    $the_big_array = [];
    
    //11.3 Open the file for reading
    //$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    //$h = fopen ("https://wordpress-317991-1667562.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/plugins/kdlcsv/uploads/".$filename,"r");
        
        //11.4 Echo the url of the file upload
        //$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        //echo $upload_dir['basedir'].$filename;
        echo "https://wordpress-317991-1667562.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/plugins/kdlcsv/uploads/".$filename;
        
        //11.5 Each line in the file is converted into an individual array
        while(($data = fgetcsv($h,10000000,",")) !== FALSE){
            
            $the_big_array[] = $data;
        }
    
//    //To display the code in a readable format
//    echo "<pre>";
//    var_dump($the_big_array);
//    echo "</pre>";
    
    //return kdl_dataarray_to_tracks($the_big_array);
}
```

Only part of my functions in file-upload.php is complete, but I am already seeing this error at WordPress.

```
This page isn’t working wordpress-317991-1667562.cloudwaysapps.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Could you help me understand what is causing the actual error? And how can I fix this issue?

Comment: use `wordpress` plugin path to your `file-upload.php`, let wordpress add that link automatically, it will work that way

Comment: I have followed your suggestion @dean and modified the code as
`
function kdl_upload_tracks_page()
{
    ?>
<h1 align="center">Upload Tracks</h1>
<!--    Upload CSV File-->
<form action="<?php echo plugins_url( 'file-upload.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Choose the File to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
}
`
However, the error still appears.